# If, And Statement not outputting accurate results in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

```
df.loc[(df['Platform'] == 'A321') and (df['Days'] <= 14), 'Mods Applicable'] = 'CFM56 9th Stage Duct'
```

I'm trying to have the output of Platforms for A321 and Days less than or equal to 14 to print out the following 'Mods Applicable' but it's not ouputting that Platforms AND the Days.

Output results:

[image: Output results]

IF & Output:

[image: IF & Output]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as far as I can see. It won't print/output anything unless you ask it to. There is no context here to work with; what exactly is the issue?

Comment: There isn't any print or any form of **output** function! what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @roganjosh I've added a screenshot of my output

Comment: @Amir I've added a screenshot in the hyperlink Output Results

Comment: Please include the text of the traceback in your question, not as an image link.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "&" instead of "and":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform': ['A123', 'A321', 'A321', 'B123'],
                   'Days': [10, 13, 20, 5]})

df.loc[(df['Platform'] == 'A321') & (df['Days'] <= 14), 'Mods Applicable'] = 'CFM56 9th Stage Duct'

print(df)

      Platform  Days       Mods Applicable
    0     A123    10                   NaN
    1     A321    13  CFM56 9th Stage Duct
    2     A321    20                   NaN
    3     B123     5                   NaN
```

I can reproduce the same error by using "and" instead of "&":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-128-7957a219684b>", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[(df['Platform'] == 'A321') and (df['Days'] <= 14), 'Mods Applicable'] = 'CFM56 9th Stage Duct'

  File "/Users/nathanielgates/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1479, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to show both methods. I'm not getting an error when I use "&". Can you add an example data frame to your question? That will make it easier to provide more specific help.

Comment: Your output is exactly what i want as results but I copied and pasted your code onto my notebook and it's still not outputting the observations with days less than 14

Comment: I'e added a screenshot of my results in the question.

Comment: What is the data type of the Days column? The numeric comparison won't work if it's string. What is the output of "df.dtypes"?

Comment: When I check the dataframe for data type with df.dtype it says AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: Make sure to include the "s" in "dtypes".

Comment: Days is int64. I think it should work if it's an integer. I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Can you find the row_index that contains the match you are looking for, and then post the output of print(df.iloc[row_index-3:row_index+3,:]) so we can look at the same data you are working with?

Comment: None of them have the correct match i'm looking for because although it outputs the Mod Applicable to all the Platforms A320, it doesn't apply the <=14 Days rule

Comment: It worked now! I was reading my < > signs wrong. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

This is because comparing a `Series` to a value also returns a `Series`. Which means that the results of `(df['Platform'] == 'A321')` and `(df['Days'] <= 14)` are `Series` of `true/false` values and it doesn't resolve to a single true or false by default. So you can't `and` it!

You can replace the `and` with `&`. So it would become:

```
df.loc[(df['Platform'] == 'A321') & (df['Days'] <= 14), 'Mods Applicable'] = 'CFM56 9th Stage Duct'
```

Comment: You clearly didn't read the comments from the answer posted an hour before yours that suggested the same thing and the OP said it didn't work.

Comment: I read that comment after I posted the answer, but I tested this code and it worked. So I didn't remove it